# How to convert a CIDR prefix to a dotted-quad netmask in Python?

Tags: python, cidr, netmask

How can I convert a CIDR prefix to a dotted-quad netmask in Python?

For example, if the prefix is `12` I need to return `255.240.0.0`.

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576483-convert-subnetmask-from-cidr-notation-to-dotdecima/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
def cidr(prefix):
    return socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack(">I", (0xffffffff << (32 - prefix)) & 0xffffffff))
```

Comment: I get this error in python 3.4: `struct.error: 'I' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295`

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer to accommodate that error checking.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a solution on the lighter side (no module dependencies):

```
netmask = '.'.join([str((0xffffffff << (32 - len) >> i) & 0xff)
                    for i in [24, 16, 8, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

And this is a more efficient one:

```
netmask = 0xFFFFFFFF & (2**(32-len)-1)
```

or, if you have difficulties counting the number of F:

```
netmask = (2**32-1) & ~ (2 ** (32-len)-1)
```

and now a possibly even more efficient (albeit more difficult to read):

```
netmask = (1<<32)-1 & ~ ((1 << (32-len))-1)
```

To get the dotted.quad version of the mask, you can use inet.ntoa to convert the above netmask.
Note: for uniformity with other message, I used 'len' as the mask length, even if I do not like to use a function name as variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do it

```
>> cidr=22
>> netmask = '.'.join([str((m>>(3-i)*8)&0xff) for i,m in enumerate([-1<<(32-cidr)]*4)])
>> print(netmask)
'255.255.252.0'
```