# How use netaddr to convert subnet mask to cidr in Python

Tags: python, cidr

How can I convert a ipv4 subnet mask to cidr notation using `netaddr` library?
Example:  `255.255.255.0 to /24`

Comment: Give it a try and show us what you've done/attempted.

Answer (score 49):

Using [`netaddr`](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```
>>> from netaddr import IPAddress
>>> IPAddress('255.255.255.0').netmask_bits()
24
```

Using [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) from stdlib:

```
>>> from ipaddress import IPv4Network
>>> IPv4Network('0.0.0.0/255.255.255.0').prefixlen
24
```

You can also do it without using any libraries: just count 1-bits in the binary representation of the netmask:

```
>>> netmask = '255.255.255.0'
>>> sum(bin(int(x)).count('1') for x in netmask.split('.'))
24
```

Comment: Could the reverse i.e. cidr to netmask be done in a one liner?

Comment: @Bilal check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23352028/244297). TLDR: `netmask = '.'.join([str((0xffffffff << (32 - prefix) >> i) & 0xff) for i in [24, 16, 8, 0]])`

Answer (score 7):

Use the following function. it is fast, reliable, and don't use any library.

```
# code to convert netmask ip to cidr number
def netmask_to_cidr(netmask):
    '''
    :param netmask: netmask ip addr (eg: 255.255.255.0)
    :return: equivalent cidr number to given netmask ip (eg: 24)
    '''
    return sum([bin(int(x)).count('1') for x in netmask.split('.')])
```

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> IPNetwork('0.0.0.0/255.255.255.0').prefixlen
24
```

Answer (score 4):

As of Python 3.5:

```
import ipaddress
ip4 = ipaddress.IPv4Network((0,'255.255.255.0'))
print(ip4.prefixlen)
print(ip4.with_prefixlen)
```

will print:

> 24
> 0.0.0.0/24

Answer (score 1):

How about this one? It does not need any additional library as well.

```
def translate_netmask_cidr(netmask):
    """
    Translate IP netmask to CIDR notation.
    :param netmask:
    :return: CIDR netmask as string
    """
    netmask_octets = netmask.split('.')
    negative_offset = 0

    for octet in reversed(netmask_octets):
        binary = format(int(octet), '08b')
        for char in reversed(binary):
            if char == '1':
                break
            negative_offset += 1

    return '/{0}'.format(32-negative_offset)
```

It is in some ways similar to IAmSurajBobade's approach but instead does the lookup reversed. It represents the way I would do the conversion manually by pen and paper.